# DE Undetermined Coefficient Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve the following non-homogeneous second order differential equation with constant coefficients with the method of undetermined coefficient but I have some problem with the particular solution, can someone help me? Thanks in advance!  

$2y^{''}+3y^{'}+y=t^{-2}$ 

My problem is that I don't know how to treat the negative power. For example considering $t^{2}$, I can write $Y=At^2+Bt+C$. But in this case what I should do?

Comment: @Moo. Did you try it ? I am almost sure that there is a typo since the particular solution involve very special functions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, so with undetermined coefficient is not possible to solve?

Comment: What makes you think this is possible? Undetermined coefficients, at least the version in most books, applies only to functions $g(t)$ of very special form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the characteristic polynomial

$$ 2r^2 + 3r + 1 = (2r+1)(r+1) = 0 \implies r = -1, -1/2 $$

So the fundamental solution is
$$ y_h(t) = c_1 e^{-t} + c_2e^{-t/2} $$

---

Now, you probably won't be able to use undetermined coefficients to obtain the particular solution, but variation of parameters can be of use. Let

$$ y_p(t) = u(t)e^{-t} + v(t)e^{-t/2} $$

Then

\begin{align}
e^{-t}u' + e^{-t/2}v' &= 0 \\
-e^{-t}u' - \frac12 e^{-t/2}v' &= \frac12 t^{-2} 
\end{align}

$$ \implies u' = -t^{-2}e^t , \quad v' = t^{-2}e^{t/2} $$

The integrals are non-elementary, but can be expressed in terms of [incomplete Gamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's clear!